# How to replace jsx substring of a props - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a shared table component. And, on this table I am trying to make those edit url dynamic. Code is straight forward and loos like:

```
const actionColumn = (
    <Link
        to={`/suppliers/ROW_ID/edit`}
        className="btn btn-info btn-xs"
        title="Edit"
    >
        <i className="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
    </Link>
);
```

```
    <Table
        actionColumn={actionColumn}
    />
```

Now on the table, I want to replace `ROW_ID` with the `row.id`

```
{list &&
    list.map((row, i) => (
         <tr>
            <td>
                {actionColumn.replace(
                    "ROW_ID",
                    row.id
                )}
            </td>
        </tr>
    ))}
```

I tried to use `.replace` but received an error: `actionColumn.replace is not a function`

Comment: A simple way is just to make `actionColumn` a function, and pass the row ID as an argument: `const actionColumn = (ROW_ID) => (...)` and then `<td>{actionColumn(row.id)}</td>`. Or make the `actionColumn` a component where the row ID is a prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function instead, one that takes the `to` prop to pass to the Link:

```
const ActionColumn = ({ to }) => (
    <Link
        to={to}
        className="btn btn-info btn-xs"
        title="Edit"
    >
        <i className="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
    </Link>
);
```

For your original layout, you can use

```
<ActionColumn to={`/suppliers/ROW_ID/edit`} />
```

To render differently, pass a different prop:

```
list.map((row, i) => (
    <td>
        <ActionColumn to={`/suppliers/${row.id}/edit`} />
    </td>
))
```

Also note that you need to balance your `<tr>` tags; you currently have a `</tr>` but no matching `<tr>`.

Comment: Hello Sir, could you help me on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67498940/input-field-losing-focus-on-each-character-type-react

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make ActionColumn a component that accepts the id as props... Then export the component

```
const ActionColumn = ({ id }) => (
    <Link
        to={`/suppliers/${id}/edit`}
        className="btn btn-info btn-xs"
        title="Edit"
    >
        <i className="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
    </Link>
);

export default ActionColumn;
```

In this component, you import the ActionColumn component and pass the row.id to it

```
{list &&
    list.map((row, i) => (
            <td>
                <ActionColumn id={row.id} />
            </td>
    ))}
```